# How to pass JWT on header with Swagger

Tags: node.js, express, header, swagger, jwt

I'm learning Swagger, Express.js and JWT with those tutorial sites.
https://scotch.io/tutorials/speed-up-your-restful-api-development-in-node-js-with-swagger
https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens#creating-a-sample-user
And the end of the article, there is a challenge to rewrite the Swagger tutorial with JWT.
I'm doing it and stuck in a problem.

My problem is that Server side(Express.js) can't get the header parameter which i set on swagger web interface.
console.log("req.headers : %j", req.headers); outputs the following log.

[image]

```
req.headers : {"host":"localhost:10010","connection":"keep-alive","access-control-request-method":"POST","origin":"http://127.0.0.1:49729","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36","access-control-request-headers":"content-type, token","accept":"*/*","referer":"http://127.0.0.1:49729/","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, sdch","accept-language":"ja,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6"}
```

There is no "x-access-token", right?
So i tested with Postman, and i got this log.

[image]

```
req.headers : {"host":"localhost:10010","connection":"keep-alive","content-length":"0","cache-control":"no-cache","origin":"chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop","x-access-token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.C0LASrYkxaU7FA3EwP8W6NQ85IlLXjdTIKnofeW8YE8","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36","postman-token":"0f3c6b0e-1f63-28ac-2b55-f58bbc209d5c","accept":"*/*","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate","accept-language":"ja,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6"}
```

Postman can do it. Besides i succeeded jwt.verify();
I think i'm missing some setting on Swagger, but i can't figure it out, so i'd like to ask advices.
Here is my Swagger codes.

```
swagger: "2.0"
...
consumes:
  - application/json
# format of the responses to the client (Accepts)
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  ...
  /movie:
    # our controller name
    x-swagger-router-controller: movie
    ...
    post:
      description: add a new movie to the list
      operationId: save
      parameters:
        - name: x-access-token
          in: header
          description: token to be passed as a header
          required: true
          type: string
        ...
      responses:
        ...
```

Thank you for your help.

---

Oct. 1st 2016

It turned out that codes protecting the root in app.js are working badly.
I created route middleware to protect the route. If i turned it off, i can get the header parameter in the Swagger operationId method.
Apparently, i should consider Swagger Route module such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-routes.

Comment: Related to CORS issue? Have you tried run [chrome](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/blob/3ca8444dd8c4f5a8de7855c757c2c7cb90ad550e/docs/cors.md#run-swagger-editor-in-a-browser-that-ignores-http-access-control) with `--disable-web-security`?

Comment: @Wilson Thank you for a comment. I tried `open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security`, but nothing changed.